# What is proper way to define Map<String, ?> method parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a custom Map to String method. It is meant to be used with any kind of Map that has String keys, not restricted to some specific map value type. The map values might have come from `javax.jms.Message.getObjectProperty(String name)` method, for example, or just be plain Strings.

Which of following is the most "proper" method signature to use, and why, or are all equal?

```
String map2String(Map<String, Object> map){...}
```

or

```
String map2String(Map<String, ?> map){...}
```

or

```
String map2String(Map<String, ? extends Object> map){...}
```

or (added edit)

```
<E> String map2String(Map<String, ? extends E> map){...}
```

or something else?

Also, the method contains for-each loop somewhat like this:

```
for(Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue().toString();
}
```

Which is "proper" type for the `entry` variable, does it matter (except the incompatible combination of `?` in the map, `Object` in the entry type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String map2String(Map<String, ?> map){...}` is correct (`? extends Object` is redundant)

The first one won't work because you wouldn't be able to call

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = {...}
map2String(myMap); // Map<String,Integer>  is not  Map<String,Object>
```

The proper type for the entry variable is `Entry<String, ?>` as you suspected.

Comment: ...looks like the correct answer, with up-votes and no disagreeing comments. Waiting a bit more before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use 1st example you posted just instead `Object` use your class type. Otherwise you must cast Object to other class or use `instanceof` and it's not good idea

```
 String map2String(Map<String, YourClass> map){...}
```

About other ones:

`String map2String(Map<String, ? extends Object> map){...}`

Well, `? extends Object` is not the best bet since every Class derived (subtype) from `Object`. There is no distinction between `? extends Object` and `?`.

`extends` wildcard you can use in case if:

```
class MyClass extends RootClass
....
class YourClass extends RootClass
....
String map2String(Map<String, ? extends RootClass> map)   // this method can fetch argumets by type of Map  `MyClass` and `YourClass`.
```

further:

```
String map2String(Map<String, ?> map){...}
```

Lets say you used `String map2String(Map map){...}` without any type. Compiler will tell you: 
*Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map should be parameterized*. But your too lazy to think about witch parameter to take. So many times I saw, people type like: `String map2String(Map<?,?> map){...}` to remove Warnings. But its bad approach.

Comment: This is for dumping any map with String keys, toString() used for value, so there is no more specific type than `Object`. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @hyde So use `E` type:  String map2String(Map<String, ? extends E> map){...} The quizzical phrase `? extends E` means that it is also OK
to add all members of a collection with elements of any type that is a subtype of E. (But you must declare your class/interface as generic with `<E>`)

Comment: Does using `<E>...<? extends E>` bring any advantage over simply using `<?>`? I don't see any, in this case.

Comment: @hyde The `?` isn't a valid declaration - ? is used as a wildcard which is used when providing a type argument, e.g. List<?> foo = ... means that foo refers to a list of some type, but we don't know what. `E` or `T` - they're just using different names for the type parameter

Comment: Well, `?` certainly compiles, and `Entry<String, ?> entry; entry.getValue().toString();` works, even checkstyle doesn't complain, so not sure what you mean by "isn't valid"...

Comment: @hyde `isn't valid (messy) in scope of code style. I don't think that is good practice to use values that you don't know their types.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with collections I would choose inheritance and generics as principles.

For instance, I would declare an interface, or an abstract base class and will pass it as the collection type parameter, like:

```
public abstract class AnimalBaseClass {
    //...
    public abstract void makeSound();
}

public interface AnimalInterface {
    public void makeSound();
}
```

Then the collection will turn into either `Map<String, AnimalInterface>` or `Map<String, ? extends AnimalBaseClass>`. This way, first map will accept any class that implements `AnimalInterface`, the second map will accept any subclass of abstract base class `AnimalBaseClass`, like `Dog extends AnimalBaseClass`.

As for your question concerning wildtypes in defining lists the answer lies in inheritance principles of java generics, namely: `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`, but `List<Integer>` or `List<? extends Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`. So, if you have `List<Integer> li` and `List<Number> ln` you can't equate `ln = li`. But if you declare `ln` as `List<? extends Number> ln` the equation will be valid. But don't forget that though the equation is valid, adding Numbers to the list will cause a compile-time error, like in `ln.add(new Float())`, so your reference will be more like a 'read-only' version of contents.

And so, your generic method will turn into:

```
public <T extends YourBaseClass> String map2String(Map<String, T> map) {
    //do something with your map and return a String object
}
```

And, if you want `Object` to be your base class, just omit '`extends YourBaseClass`'.